# How to remove time portion of DateTime in C# in DateTime object only?

Tags: c#-4.0

Here em taking input from user and then convert into DateTime when it is print on output screen it show Date and time both but i want to show only Date not time how can i do this??

```
 //INPUT
 Console.Write("Pleas Enter Date of Birth: mm-dd-yy: ");
 Date_Of_Birth = Console.ReadLine();
 //Converstion
 Date_Only = Convert.ToDateTime(Date_Of_Birth);
 //Printing no ouput Screen.
 Console.Write(Date_Only);"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control how DateTime is formatted when printed, by using `.ToString("Format")` method:

```
Console.Write(dateOnly.ToString("MM-dd-yy"));
```

or use `.ToShortDateString()` or `.ToLongDateString()` which will format the date using current culture/language settings.

Answer (score 0):

`Console.Write` has its own formatter built in:

```
 Console.Write("{0:MM-dd-yy}", Date_Only);
```

You may also consider using `Console.WriteLine` rather than `Console.Write` if you'd like it to place a line feed after the print:

```
 Console.WriteLine("{0:MM-dd-yy}", Date_Only);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert the datetime object to either date or time

Just replace DateTime.Now with your date object.

Use this for date only

```
Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
```

Use this for time only

```
Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
```